# Would this be a practical way to convert tidal energy into electrical energy?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

Imagine a structure that is held above the water by pylons that are grounded on the ocean floor. In between these pylons is a pontoon that, when tides are rising holds and lifts a heavy weight. When the tide is falling the weight is supported by the structure, which can gradually let the weight down, and in doing so create electricity. Would this be a practical or even viable way to create electricity? Why or why not?

Comment: This site doesn't usually answer "is this idea possible?" questions. They tend to turn into discussions or rapidly changing parameters. Neither of which work well. It may be better to look at the current tidal energy systems and think about why they are used instead of the method that you propose.

Comment: Some things to consider. The generation of electricity needs the generator rotor to be turned continuously at a reasonably high speed. Using a weight to turn a rotor based on the weight moving vertically due to slow tidal movement is going to be too slow. Gravity will move the weight down as the tide is going out, but how does the cable the weight is attached to turn the rotor as it is moving up on the incoming tide? Because of slow tidal movements there will be a long delay between the up & down strokes of the weight. Do as hazzey suggests research current tidal energy systems.

Comment: I was thinking that there would be some sort of mechanism so that when the pontoon is rising, the weight is also rising but when the pontoon is sinking, the weight can remain at a fixed height or sink at an independent rate to that of the tide.

Comment: [Ocean Power Technologies](http://www.oceanpowertechnologies.com/) is one company that already has similar technology. You might want to read [this](http://www.oceanpowertechnologies.com/technology/) to get a better understanding of the technology

Comment: Your latest edit just proved @hazzey's point regarding the poor fit of this sort of question and the StackExchange format: you received an answer so you edited your question, or, as hazzey put it, "They tend to turn into discussions or rapidly changing parameters".

Comment: Sorry I must have accedentily approved Murdocks edit somehow @Wasabi

Comment: I didn't mean to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with the comments about this question being a poor fit for the site, but one can nevertheless point out the common problem of tidal systems: small amount of vertical movement.

For example, say that you wanted to build a relatively small, 1 megawatt power plant based on tidal power. You have tidal movements of, say, 2 meters every 6 hours. Thus the weight you would need is:

$$ \frac{1 \mathrm{\,MW} \cdot 6 \mathrm{\,h}}{9.8 \mathrm{\frac{m}{s^2}} \cdot 2\mathrm{\,m}} = 10^9 \mathrm{\,kg}$$

If you made it out of steel, it would cost approximately 500 million dollars. And at 10 cents per kWh, this gives a repayment time on investment of 5000 years.